# Web automation, Events and Execution Flow in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, webautomation

I'm new to CasperJS and I'm trying to figure out the execution flow.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. load a page
2. stores an image of the page
3. pass this image to a function and execute it (this process is quite long: ~15 seconds)
4. wait for the function to return the result
5. use the returned value to fill a field in the form in the loaded page
6. submit the form

this is a code snippet which tries to explain the solution I came up with:

```
var globProcessedImage;

var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    }
});

casper.start('http://example.com/');

casper.then(function() {
    this.captureSelector('./image.png', '#img-node');
});

casper.waitFor(function() {
    return globProcessedImage !== undefined;
}, function then() {
    this.sendKeys('#imagePassword', globProcessedImage);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('./page.png');
});

casper.run();

casper.on('image.processed', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        globProcessedImage = 'my_result';
    }, 15000);
});
```

This results in `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globProcessedImage`.

It's still unclear to me how web automation and "external" functions mix together with CasperJS, as well as how parameters are passed between the page and casper/phantom environments.

Comment: That is not how `emit` operates. `emit` triggers the callback You should do the longProcess in a synchronous manner. Have you tried it semi-synchronously using `casper.wait(20000)`?

Comment: What I want to achieve actually is pretty straightforward: 1) Begin web automation 2) Pause automation and call external function passing a parameter 3) Retrieve result from function 4) Resume Form filling using the result. Where should I put the `casper.wait`? What if the external process takes more than 20000ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that :

```
var globProcessedImage ;

var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    }
});

casper.start('http://example.com/');

casper.options.waitTimeout = 16000;

casper.then(function() {
    this.captureSelector('./image.png', '#img-node');
    this.emit('image.processed');
});

/*
 * If you need to wait for a fix time, it's okay, but a better way would be to wait in Casper 
 * 'the thing you do with your image' in a waitFor. -> asynchronous. With this solution you combine two timers, this is not the optimized solution.
 */
casper.waitFor(function() {
    return globProcessedImage !== undefined;
}, function then() {
    this.sendKeys('#imagePassword', globProcessedImage);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('./page.png');
});

casper.run();

casper.on('image.processed', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //when you will emit this event in your script, it will set the value of globProcessedImage to 'my_result' after 15sec
        globProcessedImage = 'my_result';
    }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: Apparently `this.emit('image.processed')` will always return `undefined`, even if I force `processedValue = 'some_value';` before the `return` statement. Is this the right way to return a value to `emit`?

Comment: How do I assign a global variable in my custom event? I tried with `window.processedValue = processedValue` but it throws an error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: I edited the original question with a new snippet. A `ReferenceError` is thrown when trying to access `globProcessValue`. The original purpose of `image.processed` is to return a string value after processing a PNG, which takes up to 15-20 seconds.

Comment: My previous comments were wrong, refresh the post :p

Comment: Hey @Fanch any way to reach you outside of stackoverflow? I have a small script I would like your advice with. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Fanch-` on github, so you can chat with me on gitter :)